# .htaccess this web page has a redirect loop htaccess

Tags: html, security, .htaccess

I want to redirect all my http traffics to https in my website.

I have following codes in my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>
```

As soon as I place this file in a directory, I get an error saying "This web page has a redirect loop htaccess"

I cannot see anyother file that is causing any redirection.

What should I do?

Comment: Does it work with this RewriteRule?
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1`

Comment: I copied your exact code and it works fine.  Do you have any other rules in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` file in a higher directory?

Comment: See this on [rewriting http to https](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS), but it's recommended that you instead [Redirect to https](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL) using `mod_alias`.

Comment: Try `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on`
`RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]`

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff none of them worked for me

Comment: @drew010 That's all I have in my .htaccess file

Comment: So here is the problem:
after putting the .htaccess file, the URL changes to https://www.example.com, but the page displays an error

Comment: What if you create `https://example.com/test.html`, and access it?

Comment: Do you have **any** other `.htaccess` files on that site?

Comment: that's the only .htaccess file I have

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13192/discussion-between-shaquin-trifonoff-and-asd)

Comment: should I place the .htaccess file in the same folder as index.php or the one above it?

Answer (score 0):

This redirects all traffic on port 80 (standard http) to https:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Or, the opposite- redirect any traffic NOT on port 443 (https):

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

You can also try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: If you look into the comments, you will see that it is redirecting to HTTPS fine, but still displaying that error.